# Showing Rectangles in ListView as BarChart

Tags: windows, xaml, uwp

I am making a bar chart from a list of Rectangles in Xaml, the problem is that the listview is not rendering the Rectangles correctly, instead of making the bars, it is showing a list of **Sample.Models.BarChartRectangles** (which is the model name) text repeatedly in a list.

Here is the code,

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="80" >                                
   <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding BarChartList}">

      <Rectangle Fill="{Binding Fill}" Stroke="{Binding Stroke}" 
                 Height="{Binding Height}" Width="{Binding Width}" 
                 Margin="8,0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
      />

   </ListView>
</StackPanel>
```

Also, I have tried adding the  tag but it is not accepting Rectangles.

Answer (score 1):

Try assigning to the ItemTemplate explicitly:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="80">
  <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding BarChartList}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <Rectangle Fill="{Binding Fill}" Stroke="{Binding Stroke}"
                   Height="{Binding Height}" Width="{Binding Width}"
                   Margin="8,0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
        />
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
  </ListView>
</StackPanel>
```